# How to use numpy in optional typing

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5, typing

Lets say I want to make a function which takes a lambda function (Callable) as parameter where the lambda function takes a vector as input (defined as numpy array or numpy matrix) and returns a new vector. **How do I declare the type signature for the Callable with numpy types?**

My initial attempt looks something like this:

```
def some_func(calc_new_vector: Callable[[np.array], np.array], ...other-params...) -> SomeType:
    ...do stuff...
    ...return...
```

However, this results in an error when running the interpreter:

```
TypeError: Callable[[arg, ...], result]: each arg must be a type. Got <built-in function array>.
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Confusingly, [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is a *function* useful for creating numpy arrays. It isn't the actual `type` of the arrays created.

The type is [`np.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

So, replace `np.array` with `np.ndarray`. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have recently resolved to using the built-in `type(...)` function to print the exact types of variables I am in doubt about.. Sometimes it requires a bit detective work when using libraries such as matplotlib, but at least it has helped me finding types so far so I can put them in my function declarations.